# Handling KeyEventListener on Redis shutdown

Tags: java, redis

I have the written following subscriber on Redis which internally instantiate the listener:

```
public class RedisSubscriber extends Thread{

   String REDISHOST = "localhost";
   int REDISPORT = 6379;
   private static RedisSubscriber singleton = null;
   private Jedis sub;
   private KeyExpiredListener expireListener;

   public static synchronized RedisSubscriber getSingleton(){
      if(singleton==null){
          singleton = new RedisSubscriber();
      }
      return singleton;
   }

   private RedisSubscriber(){
       sub = new Jedis(REDISHOST, REDISPORT,0);
       expireListener = new KeyExpiredListener();
   }

   public void run() {
    //blocking call

    LOGGER.info("Inside Run - subscribing");
    try{
        sub.psubscribe(expireListener, "__key*__:*");
    }
    catch(JedisConnectionException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

public class KeyExpiredListener extends JedisPubSub {

   @Override
   public void onPSubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) {
    System.out.println("onPSubscribe " + pattern + " " + 
    subscribedChannels);
    }

   @Override
   public void onPMessage(String pattern, String channel, String 
   message)     
   {
    System.out.println("onPMessage pattern " + pattern + " " + channel  
    + " " + message);
    }
    }
}
```

Using following at the start of a server to start the RedisSubscriber-
    new Thread(RedisSubscriber.getSingleton()).start();

Now if Redis goes down, this thread will be killed . How do I make sure my subscriber connects again when Redis is up.

Thanks,
Arpit.

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection` API provides a `connect()` method. You need the `Client` in order to operate on `JedisPubSub`. So try invoking that method to reconnect. Jedis has no state over the subscribed channels AFAIK, so you have to re-subscribe to all channels.

Other clients are able to reconnect and restore the connection state transparently, so you do not get any exceptions within your application code.

Comment: Hi, Which Connection API?

Comment: See `Jedis#getClient` and `Client extends (over some levels) Connection`. To answer your original question, try `sub.connect()` in case of a disconnect.